How to access your backend APIs in wsl2 from an android emulator from windows
I have been trying to debug an API call on wsl2 from my android emulator on windows, I can access my backend from the browser on localhost:8080, but when I try accessing from the android emualtor, it just keeps failing, i was able to fix this by running the backend outside of wsl2, but i really do want the backend inside wsl2 since it has a better terminal than windows cmd
http://10.0.2.2:8080 ---> Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) from /10.0.2.16 (port 50558) after 10000ms

I tried using WSL2 ipv4 and it didn't work
